# Insert data into SQL from DataGridView with New Added Row State

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
dtNew = TryCast(bs.DataSource, DataTable).GetChanges()

If (dtNew IsNot Nothing) Then
For Each dr As DataRow In dtNew.Rows
      Select Case (dr.RowState)
          Case DataRowState.Added

              Dim strSQLDelete As String = String.Empty
              strSQLDelete = String.Format("insert into employeebenefittran (empbenefitcode,amount,calamount,refno,taxclass,source,empbenefitdate,period,cycle,empno) values ('{0}',{1},{1},'{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')", dr(0), dr(1), "", dr(2), "Y", Date.Parse(String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", strPeriod.Substring(0, 4), strPeriod.Substring(4, 2), 1)), strPeriod, "0E", strEmpNo)

              Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(sDBConnection)
              If sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlConn.Open()

                  Using cmdSQLDelete As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQLDelete, sqlConn)
                  cmdSQLDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
                  End Using

              If sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlConn.Close()
              End Using
    End Select
Next
End If
```

I have coded to Insert my New Added Data from DataGridView, with datasource. However, I found that I need always to click to next row after I have completed key in a row of data or it will found nothing is my datasource or datatable and skip the insert. 
* mean dtNew will always be nothing until I click a new row on datagridview, this is not a good User Experience.

Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: When they add a new row maybe give them a form to fill in?

Comment: I used the most dummy way, gcvYTDBIK.AddNewRow() on before getchange of the DataTable, to temporarily solve this issue. However, I am not sure if that is any other issue would be raised since that is a "Trick" played. Thank ThatGuy.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to your grid.  It appears that you may already be doing that.  You can then call `EndUpdate` on the `BindingSource` when you're ready to save and that will commit any pending changes to the underlying `DataTable`.

As for the actual saving, you're complicating something that is very simple.  Firstly, you don't need that `Select Case`.  The `GetChanges` method allows you to specify one or more `DataRowState` values and the resulting `DataTable` will contain only changed rows with that state.  Change this:

```
dtNew = TryCast(bs.DataSource, DataTable).GetChanges()
```

to this:

```
dtNew = TryCast(bs.DataSource, DataTable).GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
```

and then you can remove the `Select Case`.

By the way, you should NEVER be using `TryCast` and then chaining another member onto it.  The whole point of `TryCast` is that it can return `Nothing`.  If that happens in your code then a `NullReferenceExcpetion` will be thrown.  If you know for a fact that that will never happen then you should be using `DirectCast` rather than `TryCast` in the first place.

There's also no good reason to be using a loop like that.  You should be creating a data adapter with an appropriate `InsertCommand` and then passing your `DataTable` to its `Update` method.  That will save all changes in that `DataTable` as a batch.

There's probably no good reason to be calling `GetChanges` anyway.  You'd only do that if there might be changes of a type other than additions that you don't want to save at the same time.  If you want to save all changes or there can only be new rows then you may as well just call `Update` on a data adapter and pass the original `DataTable`.

Comment: I have tried the DirectCast is not different with the trycase, both will get Nothing for DataTable. The reason I used select case is the AddNew is only one of the function Is implemented, I will still further implement Delete, Update after I have solved the current Issue. Thank for your suggestion, You have exploded my viewpoint, Jmcihinney.

Comment: If `TryCast` ever fails in that code then `DirectCast` will fail too. If `TryCast` will never fail in that code then `DirectCast` will never fail either. Both have a specific purpose so use the one that applies to the specific situation in question. There is NEVER, EVER a situation where it's not 100% clear which should be used.

Comment: Just use a data adapter and save the lot in a batch. If you want to test with just one type of change then make that decision while testing. Don't write code to enforce the situation.  You might like to read this, paying special attention to the examples that use a data adapter: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&highlight=